# One database, multiple .NET MVC 5 instances

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, database-design, entity-framework-6

I have written c# ASP.NET MVC 5 with EF 6 application. I have 2 clients. Fore each of them I need to modify the app slightly.

I wont them to share one database, but with separate table names, which I achieved by:

```
string dbPrefix = "Client1";    
modelBuilder.Entity<Request>().ToTable(dbPrefix + "_TableName);
...
```

Is this possible, and is there a better way?

**UPDATE**
Let me try to explain this way. There is an app that has 10 tables and I prefixed table names buy method above.
2 (or more) versions (instances) of the app should occupy the same database, but each has it's own tables. No sharing between them. There could as well be different apps.

App resides in public/laf and table prefix is laf

App resides in public/perla and table prefix is perla

...

Everything is separate except the database.

The idea is to have all production databases in one place, for easier backup and other maintenance, as well as price.

I hope this makes more sense :)

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Do you mean you want the 2 apps to use the same tables, but have them use different entity names in your code?  Or do you mean you want each app to use different tables in the database, maybe using the same entity names?

Comment: Cloning the database schema will create you many headaches. Especially using different table names for different clients.

Comment: That I figured out the hard way, but still don't have better alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "better way" you are seeking is to use the same tables, but add an additional column that identifies the client that is using it. Then you can program the application so each client only can see and edit their own data.

Typically, you would add a table to identify the client:

```
|  ClientID  |  Name                    |
|------------|--------------------------|
|  1         |  Client 1                |
|  2         |  Client 2                |
|------------|--------------------------|
```

Then you would use the ClientID as a foreign key on all of your other tables:

```
|  SomeTableID  |  ClientID                |   Other fields...
|---------------|--------------------------|
|  1            |  2                       |
|  2            |  1                       |
|---------------|--------------------------|
```

Then in all of your queries, you would add ClientID to the  where clause:

```
// clientId is the currently logged on.
// Typically, this would be passed into your data access code
// from your business layer.
int clientId = 1;

var query = for someTable as Entities.SomeTable
    where (someTable.ClientID == clientId)
    select someTable
```

The where clause will prevent each client from seeing the other's data. You don't have a table structure that grows exponentially with each client, and maintenance is simpler.

In addition to these benefits, you gain another one. It is now very trivial to create reports that span all clients in case you need them for administrative purposes.

Comment: I'm accepting the answer, but it doesn't solve my problem. I was not considering this solution, as this particular application will be modified for every client. Tables (models) can be different. But yes, I do agree that for normal application this is good solution, and for my problem I will simply need to use one db for one client.